# "Add to Favorite / Remove" - Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, getelementbyid

I want to create a  "Add to favorite" & "Remove from favorite".

When I add the favorite, I change the ID of the DIV for remove.
I can successfully add to favorite but I can't undo.

*This code for add*

```
    $('#addToFavoriteButton').click(function (event) {
        var ItemID = $('#addToFavoriteButton').data('itemid');
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('/system/ajax.php', {
            AddFavID: ItemID 
        }, function (response) {
            document['getElementById']('addToFavorite').id = 'RemoveFavoriteButton';
        });
    });
```

This code for remove

```
$('#RemoveFavoriteButton').click(function (event) {
        var ItemID = $('#RemoveFavoriteButton').data('itemid');
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('/system/ajax.php', {
            RemoveFavbidID: ItemID
        }, function (response) {
            document['getElementById']('RemoveFavoriteButton').id = 'addToFavoriteButton';
        });
    });
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You can't assign an event handler to an element by ID and then change that ID to make it run something else - the event handler is already assigned and doesn't care what the ID is when you click it.  Ideally you should just have an add button and a remove button and toggle visibility.

Comment: You're missing an opening single quote here: $.post(/system/ajax.php'

Comment: You have a discrepency between the id you set when you add to favorite and the id you try to grab when you try to remove. I would also suggest a class name rather than changing the id. Esp if there may be more than one button with this id as id's absolutely have to be unique.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `document['getElementById']` instead of `document.getElementById` or even just `$('#RemoveFavoriteButton')`? Mixing technologies and access patterns tends to confuse matters even more.

Comment: @Archer ; I see the ' Add and remove ' function on some websites via a single button. I can't add multiple IDs in the same div. then I guess it's supposed to be like this: `<span id="addToFavoriteButton_<ID>" class="RemoveFavoriteButton_<ID>">..` I'II do the adding with ID, I'll do the removing with the class. Does that make sense?

Comment: @scrappedcola ; You're absolutely right. So I added ID number to the end. for example; `addToFavoriteButton_<ID>`

Comment: I've added an answer showing the problem with your approach (changing the ID), and how to do it without.

Comment: @Archer Alternatively, It would be better for me to do this is the background. If the data is registered in the database, it will remove.. :)

Comment: You need to do this in the background either way, but that won't update the UI.  You really need to do both - update the UI so the user sees that they've added it, and update the database as well.  The problem you've faced is a very simple UI problem - don't go changing the backend for this. Only fix that if it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you are assigning an event handler to a button and then changing the ID of that button, expecting it to trigger different code when it is clicked.  That is wrong.

If you change the ID of an element it will still trigger the event handler that you originally assigned to it.  See this example...

```js
$("#button1").on("click", function() {
  alert("you clicked button 1 - my id is " + this.id);
});

$("#button2").on("click", function() {
  alert("you clicked button 2");
});

// change the ID of #button1 to #button2
$("#button1").attr("id", "button2");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button 1</button><br/>
<button id="button2">button 2</button><br/>
```

What makes more sense is to have a button to add a favourite, and a button to remove a favourite.  You just hide the remove button until add is clicked, and vice-versa.

Like this...

```js
var $add = $("#addFavourite");
var $remove = $("#removeFavourite");

$add.on("click", function() {
  $add.hide();
  $remove.show();
  
  var itemId = $add.data("item-id");
  alert("adding item " + itemId);

  // do your AJAX stuff to add the favourite here
  
});

$remove.on("click", function() {
  $add.show();
  $remove.hide();
  
  var itemId = $add.data("item-id");
  alert("removing item " + itemId);

  // do your AJAX stuff to remove the favourite here
  
});
```

```css
#removeFavourite {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addFavourite" data-item-id="123">add favourite</button>
<button id="removeFavourite" data-item-id="123">remove favourite</button>
```

Comment: Really thank you! I started thinking I couldn't do it with Javascript. Therefore, so I thought about working in the background. -- When I click on each button it automatically add  "liked " to the class of DIV. For example; `<span class="like-icon with-tip"></span>`.. If I clicked: `<span class="like-icon with-tip liked"></span>` Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: I solved this issue with your help. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggested that you change the class instead of the id, since the id must be unique.

Or you can always use [HTML5 data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), which you can use for both CSS styling (using attribute selector) and JS use (with dataset or jQuery's .data () method). [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="el" data-test="data"></div>
```

vanilla javascript

```
var el = document.getElementById('el');
el.dataset.test // 'data'
```

by the way how you get the id is wrong -

```
document['getElementById']('RemoveFavoriteButton').id
```

You must use

vanilla javascript

```
document.getElementById('RemoveFavoriteButton').id;
```

jQuery

```
$('#RemoveFavoriteButton')attr('id');
```

Comment: It will still trigger the add function, no matter how you change the ID or what you change it to.

Comment: I know, I was just saying that the way he was getting the id was wrong. You in your first example explain that as you change the id, as I did, and for further you put the two elements with the same id.

Comment: Yes, I explain why it is incorrect and give a working example to show exactly what the problem is.  I then go on to explain how to resolve it.  This answer doesn't fix any problems at all.